# Compare linear models with and without an interaction effect

Tags: r, regression, anova, interaction, linear-model

I want to compare the following two linear models:

```
model 1: y = mean + A + B  
model 2: y = mean + A + A*B
```

Is model 2 equivalent to y = mean + A + B + A*B? Can I use `anova(model1, model2)` in R to compare the two nested models?

If not, how can I compare them in R?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Unless you know what you are doing (and I don't...), one normally would keep in the model the main effect for any term that appears in a higher-order model term, as your `B` is here. Quite often the main "effect" may not be significant in the `summary()` information for tests of whether the coefficient is equal to 0, but the "effect" of `B` is bound up with the interaction term `A*B`, and retaining the main effect makes interpretation of the interaction term easier to grasp.

Comment: Thank you, Gavin. I got two design matrix from an external software, which correspond to the two linear models in my question. I want to compare the two models in R to test the interaction term. If I could get the design matrix of the interaction term from those of the two main effects, it would be easier. Do you know how to do that? Thank you!

Comment: In R, if you want to test the interaction then you want `m1 <- lm(y ~ A + B, data = foo)` and `m2 <- lm(y ~ A * B, data = foo)`, then `anova(m1, m2)` will give an F test for the interaction. Note that `m2` could be written longhand as `m2 <- lm(y ~ A + B + A:B, data = foo)`, wherein the nesting become clear as `A:B` is the interaction term and its coefficient would be = 0 in `m1`. Note the intercept/constant term is implied in these model formulae.

Comment: Gavin, thank you very much! That is the answer I am looking for. Just want to make it clear: it is not correct to use m2 <- lm(y ~ A + A*B)?

Answer (score 3):

In R, if you want to test the interaction then you want

```
m1 <- lm(y ~ A + B, data = foo)
m2 <- lm(y ~ A * B, data = foo)
```

then

```
anova(m1, m2)
```

will give an F test for the interaction.

Note that `m2` could be written longhand as

```
m2 <- lm(y ~ A + B + A:B, data = foo)
```

wherein the nesting become clear as `A:B` is the interaction term and its coefficient would be = 0 in `m1`. Note the intercept/constant term is implied in these model formulae.

Note that in

```
m2 <- lm(y ~ A + A*B)
```

the first `A` is redundant as `A*B` expands to `A + B + A:B`. R is clever enough to work out you don't want the following model `A + A + B + A:B` and only includes `A` once.

In R, `A` and `B` would be factors containing a recording of the label or type of each observation. If by your notation you have 3 levels/types in `A` and 4 in `B`, then `A` and `B` would be *factor* **vectors** with `length(levels(A))` and `length(levels(B))` equal to 3 and 4 respectively. R will create the design matrix for the model from the symbolic representation you provided via the formula. To see what R is doing, you can do `head(model.matrix(~ A + A*B, data = foo))` to see the first 6 rows of the design matrix. This is coded using treatment contrasts but others are available. See `?contr.sum` for details on the various contrast types built into R.

Comment: Hello Gavin, thank you again. I have a further question/case. If A and B are n*3 and n*4 matrix, respectively, and I do not have the design matrix for the interaction term A*B, can I still apply the method above? Or do I need to calculate the design matrix for A*B first?

Comment: I added the response to this additional Q into my original answer.